# Why do I get "duplicate symbol reference" when including two cgo based libraries?

Tags: sqlite, go, cgo, unqlite

I'm trying to build (go build) the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/d2g/unqlitego"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Erm Compile?")
}
```

and I get an error:

> duplicate symbol reference: __moddi3 in both github.com/d2g/unqlitego( .text) and github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3(.text)

I'm running go version go1.3.1 windows/386.

Am I doing something wrong? How would you resolve this sort of issue?

Is this OS/Go Version/Architecture specific bug? (I'd appreciate "it works for me" with the output from your `go version`)

I've put this all in a repo so you should be able to just `go get github.com/d2g/issue-duplicate_symbol`.

As per comments looks like a Windows 386 issue logged on: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8702

Comment: Darn: go version go1.3.1 windows/amd64, but I don't have `gcc` on my `%PATH%`. Is it possible you have `sqlite3.dll` somewhere else on your disk, that might interfere in this compilation?

Comment: If I comment out either library it compiles. Which suggests it's to do with how they interact at compile time?

Comment: Weird, because Go usually does magic to keep C symbol names from conflicting as long as they're wrapped by separate packages.

Comment: Works for me go1.3 Windows amd64

Comment: Just updated to 1.3.1, still works on Windows amd64

Comment: I'm getting the same issue using 1.2 Windows/386.

Comment: Looks like it might be a 386 issue then?

Comment: Confirmed. Changing GOARCH to 386 causes the conflict.

Comment: Windows specific issue: see https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8756, won't be fixed until version 1.5

Comment: go version go1.3.2 linux/amd64
it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

@AndrewN notes that this is a Windows specific issue: see [golang.org/issue/8756](https://golang.org/issue/8756) or original issue at [code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8756](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8756), won't be fixed until version 1.5.

(Documenting so this does not look like unanswered question).